# Strange Array.slice behavior

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain "slice" behavior?

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
console.log(arr.slice(0, 4)); // [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
console.log(arr.slice(4, 4)); // []
```

Why the second array is empty? Should not it be ['e','f'] ?
If omit "end" param, the result as expected.

Comment: Um not "four elements" but rather "until index four" -> `arr.slice(4, 6)`

Comment: Please read the documentation for slice() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice I think you are confusing it with how splice works.

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

`arr.slice(4, 4)` will return the items beginning at index = 4 to index = 4; `4-4=0` so your array has got a length of `0`

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
console.log(arr.slice(0, 4)); // [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
console.log(arr.slice(4, 4)); // []
console.log(arr.slice(2, 4));
console.log(arr.slice(1, 2));
```

Comment: Ok, i got it. Thank you. I confused that "end" is an index and not amount of elements to fetch. (PHP legacy) :)

Answer (score 2):

According to [official docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) it:

> Returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included). The original array will not be modified.

Meaning that, you start at the index 4 and u end at that index, so literally you took no elements since the difference between start and end index is 0, so no elements are taken.